# Ionescu Tulcea kernel

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $(\mathcal{X}_i, \mathcal{A}_i)$ be a measurable space,
$\kappa_i : \mathcal{A}_i \times \prod_{j=1}^i \mathcal{X}_j \to [0,1]$
be a Markov kernel for $i \in \mathbb{N}$
and $\mu_1$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal{A}_1$.
Ionescu-Tulcea says that for each $i \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ there exists a unique probability measure $\mu_i$ on $\bigotimes_{j=1}^i \mathcal{A}_j$ with
$$ \mu_i(A_1 \times \dots \times A_i) = \mu_\infty
\left(A_1 \times \dots \times A_i \times \prod_{j=i+1}^\infty \mathcal{X}_j \right) $$
**Edit**: With some encouragement from a friend who was so kind to review this question I think I can simplify my question a bit:

Notice that $\kappa_1(\cdot \mid x)$ defines a measure for each $x \in \mathcal{X}_1$. Let $\mu_x$ be the Ionescu-Tulcea measure generated by $\kappa_1(\cdot \mid x)$ and $\kappa_2, \kappa_3, \dots$.
Let $\tau(A \mid x) = \mu_x(A)$. Is $\tau$ a (Markov) kernel?

Any conditions enabling this existence or references to litterature about this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is easily proved using a Dynkin-class argument.
See [here](https://github.com/harderj/speciale/blob/master/tex/main.pdf) in the section on measure theory.